# Can't split the text with white space

Tags: string, powershell, split

I want to split the text `"Account D:\Bank\Account"` with `white space` , so the parts will be `Account` and `D:\Bank\Account` , but it appear some error message , what's the problem?

here is my code

```
$Path_info = "Account D:\Bank\Account"
$Account = $Path_info.Split(" ")
write-host $Acoount[0]
```

error message

[image]

Comment: try without the typo `write-host $Account[0]` ;)

Comment: Use the [strict mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730970.aspx) to catch typos in variable names, non-existing properties and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in

```
write-host $Acoount[0]
```

should be

```
write-host $Account[0]
```

Except for this, your code works fine.